# Login Page refreshes magento 1.9

Tags: cookies, authentication, refresh

When the customer tries to login, the page just refreshes. I tried various tutorial online like adding form key and increasing the cookie value. Sometimes i m able to login and sometimes the refresh problem occurs. My website is www.laptek.in

Comment: Does it only refresh if the supplied login informations are correct? Sounds like a cookie problem.

Comment: yes it only refreshes....

Comment: Delete your cookies. Also check that the cookies contain a valid path. Also it seems it creates multiple frontend cookies, one for .laptek.in and one without the first dot.

Comment: thanks for reply. i m new to magento. so can you tell me how to delete cookies

Comment: Your browser manages your cookies...

Comment: i cleared my browser history and also checked with other laptop. its still the same. although it works sometimes. i need a permanent solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First go to magento's root directory and navigate to var/session and clear everything in there.
Then navigate to the backend

> system>configuration>web>session cookie management>cookie domain

and add there laptek.in.

If you just upgraded your magento installation from an older version then follow this guide. Solved my issue when I encountered it.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104982/new-registration-page-refreshing-without-any-changes